# How to get CTR value from google AdSense using Google.Apis.AdSense

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, adsense

I am using Google.Apis.AdSense to get AdSense Data from C# windows form..
i can get adsense info and Metric Report, using Metric i can optians some values such as

```
["PAGE_VIEWS",
"INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS",
"CLICKS","AD_REQUESTS_CTR",
"INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_CTR",
"COST_PER_CLICK","AD_REQUESTS_RPM",
"INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_RPM",
"AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE","EARNINGS"]
```

here a code for this process:

```
public AdsenseReportsGenerateResponse GenerateReport(Account adSenseAccount, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var reportRequest = service.Accounts.Reports.Generate(
        adSenseAccount.Id, startDate.ToString(DateFormat), endDate.ToString(DateFormat));

    reportRequest.Metric = new List<string>
    {
     "PAGE_VIEWS","INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS", "CLICKS","AD_REQUESTS_CTR","INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_CTR",
     "COST_PER_CLICK","AD_REQUESTS_RPM","INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_RPM", "AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE","EARNINGS"
    };
    reportRequest.Dimension = new List<string> { "DATE" };
    reportRequest.Sort = new List<string> { "+DATE" };

    // Run report.
    var reportResponse = reportRequest.Execute();
    ReportUtils.FillGapsDates(reportResponse, startDate, endDate);

    if (!reportResponse.Rows.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        ReportUtils.DisplayHeaders(reportResponse.Headers);
        Console.WriteLine("Showing data from {0} to {1}", reportResponse.StartDate, reportResponse.EndDate);
        return reportResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

First issue:
Although the data are not identical, they are similar. Why?

**Second issue (important):
How or where can i get CTR Value?** 
Currently, we calculated the following equation:

```
INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_CTR * 2 * 100
```

Is this correct?